# How do I render 3D objects in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, 3d

Hy everyone ✌,

I try now to build a 3D Widgets in Flutter, something like this both Widgets in the image:

[image: 3D Widgets Design Image]

have anybody a idea how can be this created? Or isn't impossible?

Comment: Everything is possible if you really want to

Comment: You have the right @AlbertoMiola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Matrix4` transforms to achieve 3D rotations, however, Flutter uses **Skia** for rendering, which only supports 2D shapes. Hence, you would need to draw **3 shapes** to achieve your example because Skia cannot figure out where the first shape would need to overlap the second and vise versa.

You would somehow need to figure out what paths make exactly the cuts you can see in your image. The gradients would not be a problem because you can create shaders ([`Gradient` extends `Shader`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Gradient-class.html)) and paint them onto the 2D shapes using [`Canvas.drawRect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawRect.html) with `Paint.shader` and rotating the canvas before that using [`Canvas.transform`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/transform.html), which takes a `matrix4` as a `Float64List`.

However, the Flutter rendering engine is not really made for 3D operations like this, so you need a bit of setup to make it work.
See [this **Pub** search](https://pub.dev/packages?q=3d) for some options to render 3D objects in Flutter and Dart in general and [this **gskinner** vignette](https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter_vignettes/tree/master/vignettes/indie_3d) for another implementation of rendering 3D objects in Flutter.